# More efficient/cleaner way of passing a value to a methods options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery.barRating.js to have ratings on each div element that is rendered to my page.

I have to render the following html for every div.. currently four are rendered.

```
<div class="star-ratings">
              <p>Rate This Video</p>
              <div class="stars stars-example-fontawesome-o">
                <select class="example-fontawesome-o" name="rating" data-current-rating="" autocomplete="off">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  ..........
                </select>
                <span class="title current-rating">
                  Current rating: <span class="value">5</span>
                </span>
                <span class="title your-rating hidden">
                  Your rating: <span class="value"></span>&nbsp;
                  <a href="#" class="clear-rating"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
```

And each rating select is initiated by the following script, which takes an option initialRating - This tells the script how many stars should be highlighted, out of ten.

```
var arrOfRatings = [5,4,6,7];

$('.example-fontawesome-o').each(function (i, obj) { // Each instance of .example-fontawesome-o

    $(obj).barrating({
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars-o',
        showSelectedRating: false,
        initialRating: parseFloat(arrOfRatings[i]), // Array set up earlier with ratings in
        onSelect: function (value, text) {

            var starRatingSelector = $(this)[0].$elem.parent().parent(); // div.stars.stars-example-fontawesome-o
            var starRatingChildCurrentRating = starRatingSelector.children('.current-rating'); // .stars.stars-example-fontawesome-o span.title.current-rating.hidden
            var starRatingChildYourRating = starRatingSelector.children('.your-rating'); // .stars.stars-example-fontawesome-o span.title.your-rating.hidden


            if (!value) {
                obj.barrating('clear'); // Clear rating if there was a problem
            } else {

                starRatingChildCurrentRating.addClass('hidden');


                starRatingChildYourRating.removeClass('hidden')
                        .find('span')
                        .html(value);
            }

        },
        onClear: function (value, text) {
            console.log($(this));
            var clearSelector = $(this)[0].$elem.parent().parent();


            clearSelector.children('.current-rating')
                    .removeClass('hidden')
                    .end()
                    .find('.your-rating')
                    .addClass('hidden');
        }
    });


});
```

The rating is in the html above -

```
<span class="title current-rating">
                      Current rating: <span class="value">5</span>
                    </span>
```

But at the moment, I am having to pass in an array of the ratings which I also must render to pass into the options.  `initialRating: parseFloat(arrOfRatings[i])`

I have had to do it this way as I cant access $(this) until the script gets past the following

```
$(obj).barrating({
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars-o',
        showSelectedRating: false,
        initialRating: parseFloat(arrOfRatings[i]),
        onSelect: function (value, text) { // Can only access $(this) here}
```

So In a cleared summary i wondered if there is a way to get the value 5 out of `<span class="value">5</span>` and pass it to `initialRating` without the use for an additional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the order of the child elements matches the order in your array, and the only elements with the class `current-rating` are the the ones you need, you can use

```
initialRating: parseFloat($('.current-rating').eq(i).find('.value').text()),
```

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Sorry I forgot to get the actual value :) Fixed it.